Docker wordpress cannot connect to local host mysql database
I have a docker image with wordpress (https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) and i want to connect to local host mariadb database. Evertime i tried to open my local ip http://192.168.18.79:8080 it always shows "Error establishing a database connection"
sudo docker run --name  wordpress -p 8080:80 -d \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=192.168.18.79 \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER='wordpressuser' \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD='password' \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME='wordpress_container' \
  -e WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT='[KEY]' \
  wordpress

i got the [KEY] from https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
I have tried to open the port for mariadb by changing bind-address in /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf to 0.0.0.0
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1742/docker-proxy   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      601/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      603/nginx: master p 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      667/mariadbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      603/nginx: master p

In MariaDB i already created the DB and Grant access to the user
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE wordpress_container DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'wordpressuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON wordpress_container.* TO 'wordpressuser';

justin@debian:~$ sudo docker logs wordpress
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
No 'wp-config.php' found in /var/www/html, but 'WORDPRESS_...' variables supplied; copying 'wp-config-docker.php' (WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT WORDPRESS_DB_HOST WORDPRESS_DB_NAME WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD WORDPRESS_DB_USER WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT)
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun May 26 10:03:28.196354 2024] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.59 (Debian) PHP/8.2.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun May 26 10:03:28.196464 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
172.17.0.1 - - [26/May/2024:10:03:54 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 500 285 "-" "curl/7.88.1"

I have tried to ping mariadb from wordpress image got an error "Connection timed out". I tried the same for ssh it connects successfully. I don't know what is wrong
justin@debian:~$ sudo docker exec -it wordpress /bin/bash
root@85fef2d89d2f:/var/www/html# telnet 192.168.18.79 3306
Trying 192.168.18.79...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
root@85fef2d89d2f:/var/www/html# telnet 192.168.18.79 22
Trying 192.168.18.79...
Connected to 192.168.18.79.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2


Ensure that the wordpressuser has the correct permissions. Connect to your MySQL server and run:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress_container.* TO 'wordpressuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Also try to use a custom docker network:
sudo docker network create wordpress-net

Run WordPress Container on Custom Network:
sudo docker run --name wordpress --network wordpress-net -p 8080:80 -d \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=192.168.18.79 \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpressuser \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password \
  -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_container \
  -e WORDPRESS_AUTH_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_NONCE_KEY='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_AUTH_SALT='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_SECURE_AUTH_SALT='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_LOGGED_IN_SALT='[KEY]' \
  -e WORDPRESS_NONCE_SALT='[KEY]' \
  wordpress



hey, thanks for the answer. I tried running all the commands turns out the connection got blocked by firewall. I run the command sudo ufw disable and it worked now

Please stop putting "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" after GRANT/ CREATE USER. Its not needed.
